# Problems deploying batch file to bootstrap windows EC2 instance

Tags: git, batch-file, deployment, aws-cloudformation

I have a problem with the line endings in a batch file I'm trying to deploy as a part of a cloudformation bootstrapping.  No matter what I do the file seems to end up with LF line ending rather than CRLF.  The file shows as a single line and does not properly execute.  (Note: the file executes as expected when I RDP and paste the data into a text editor.)

Here is a description of the deployment process:

1. I create the batch file on my mac in IntelliJ.
2. I assign the line end to CRLF in the file menu.
3. I ensure that my .gitattributes  has the following line:
   `*.bat text eol=crlf`
4. I push the file to Gerrit.
5. Jenkins pulls and builds the project and deploys the file to S3 using SBT and AWS JAVA API.
6. CloudFormation template installs AWS CLI from a .msi file provided by Amazon.
7. CloudFormation template executes an `AWS S3 CP` to deploy the batch file to the machine's startup directory.

What could be messing with my line ends?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to deploy successfully after cleaning my Jenkins workspace.  Looks like the Jenkins' git cache was gumming up the works.